# How to get container image's tags list?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I want to get the tag list of container images in my private repository on Docker Hub.
In the case of the public repository, I can get the tag list following command.

```
curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/centos/tags
```

How to do the same operation in private repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you installed Docker registry v2 server, and the image is `ubuntu`.

(You need adjust with real image name.)

```
$ curl --cacert certs/registry-ca-cert.crt -X GET https://myregistry:5000/v2/ubuntu/tags/list

> {"name":"ubuntu","tags":["14.04"]}
```

Comment: thank you for reply. But I don't have private registry. I have the dockerHub account and I put the image in private repository.